# Passing parameter to window panel from grid panel in EXTJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

```
{
    icon: 'images/delete.png', 
    tooltip: 'Edit',

    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            var edit = Ext.create('AM.view.user.Uploadfile').show();
            //here I want to pass parameters to get in window panel     
    }
}
```

The code that I have written and want the parameter to be passed like the row id where the icon is clicked on window panel.

Comment: Why has your handler that parameters? Can you elaborate that button?

Comment: actually its under the grid layout,I am using a button as a action column.And I want to pass 'id' when clicking on it to the window panel.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the API you will see that the **[handler](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action-cfg-handler)** has the arguments

- view : The owning TableView.
- rowIndex : The row index clicked on.
- colIndex : The column index clicked on.
- item : The clicked item (or this Column if multiple items were not configured).
- e : The click event.
- **record** : The Record underlying the clicked row

Where the last one is interesting for you. So you can do it like so

```
handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e , record) {
    var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', { 
          autoShow: true, 
          html: record.data.firstname + ' ' + record.data.lastname 
    });
}
```

And here is a working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwLCM/)**

Answer (score 0):

It is a button on a actioncolumn. To pass the Id to a window you can retrieve the row data by getting it from the record parameter.

```
columns: [
    { text: 'Id', dataIndex: 'Id', width: 50 },
    {
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        width: 100,
        text: 'Delete',
        align: 'center',
        items: [{
            icon: '../images/delete.png',
            tooltip: 'Delete',
            handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record) {
                myWin.id = record.data.Id; //where myWin is a reference to the window object and id is just a config.
            }
        }]
    }
]
```

Comment: what does the above line  win = Ext.getCmp('somewindow'); means here.

Comment: FYI: The `rowIdenx` doesn't necessarily need to be the index of the record within the store. At least I never heard of such a convention. Even if it may be so in some cases I would not rely on it till they rename it recordIndex ;)

Comment: Thank you sra. I have this code in development :o, I'm gonna fix it right now with your example :)

Comment: hehe, always a pleasure ;)